# "You already applied for this job" indicator on Job search result page

Tags: feature-request, jobs

There is no message/button on the job search listing page to indicate - "you have already applied for this job". We need to open one page each job posting to check "applied/not applied" message.

A simple message on the job listing page can save one click and bandwidth per job posting.

Comment: I agree, but the answer doesn't solve the problem. I am asking for a button on the listing page that doesn't exists.

Comment: What answer? There's no answer there, and I voted to reopen it, as it was wrongfully closed in the first place

Comment: Actually "Should Indicate which Positions I've Already Applied For" is marked duplicate to another thread and the answer there is not solving this

Comment: I know, that's what I was trying to say.